# Proper Terminology for Group of Databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, reporting, terminology

Alright, this may seem trivial, but my colleagues and I have been wondering if there is a widely accepted term for a group of databases. For example, we work in a reporting environment and run reports from 14 or so completely seperate databases nationwide.

Collectivly we just refer to them as "The Database Group" or "Data Cluster" but I don't think either of these are standardized terms, and I am worried they may actually conflict with other, real terminology.

Comment: If the databases are on the same server XXX, you could call them "XXX databases".  Otherwise, "The Reporting Databases" seems like a useful name in that context.

Comment: Yep, seems simple enough lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per wiki, A "database management system" (DBMS) is a suite of computer software providing the interface between users and a database or databases.

Definitely DB Group and Data Cluster is not suitable here.

Probably you can check for FEDERATED DATABASE which is used for multiple autonomous Databases.

Comment: Well the DBMS we use to access these individual DB's is SQL Server 2008. I will look into the term "Federated Database" although it sounds like something out of a Joss Whedon sci fi flick.

Comment: I did some research, and Federated Database seems to be the proper terminology, for lack of a more precise designation. So I guess when we are looking at multiple individual databases within SQL Server or SAP Business Objects, we are technically looking at a Federated Database